# Windows Defender Exclusions

Tags: anti-virus, windows-defender

If a virus added itself to windows defender exclusions, it will never be scanned. However would windows defender still remove its startup registry keys and scheduled tasks?

Windows defender is the only antivirus allowing exclusions to be added in such a simple way through powershell and i see it as a big issue. If it removes the viruses startup methods it would be a way to minimize this issue at least partly.

Edit: I know it CAN remove the entries but i am wondering how is it handling this issue currently

Comment: How would it gain admin perms?

Comment: User runs it as admin or it bypasses the UAC?

Comment: ...then the AV failed its job & the user failed theirs. Invite it in & give it perms… that's how the bad actors get past us, all day, every day.

Comment: @WindowsDefenderExcl - It’s nearly impossible to disable Windows Defender, while an exception could be created, is this an actual problem you have experienced?

Comment: Yes, I noticed a folder was added to exclusions, downloaded malwarebytes and turns out it was a virus.

Answer (score 0):

A virus can only add itself to the exclusions list by running in an
elevated environment. It probably did ask for elevation and you granted it,
or you're running with UAC disabled (which is asking for trouble).

If the virus is known, Windows Defender will find it sooner or later
when it scans the registry, which it does regularly.
The exclusions only cover the disk, but not the registry.
With luck, Windows Defender will detect the bad registry entry from
the name of the executable of the virus (if it's always the same).

But there can be no defense from a virus that was granted administrator
permissions. Adding startup entries to the registry is only one
of very many ways that it can totally infect the computer.
This is why it's often advised to do a clean installation of Windows
after any infection.